# Query on JOIN tables

Tags: mysql

I am working on an exercise for a databases class, but I am not able to finish the last exercise.

The question is: Write a query that returns the name of all persons that like at least two people with green eyes. Eliminate duplicates from your query result.

Two tables are given, namely : 
Persons {*id*, name, address, age, eyeColor, gender}

and

Likes {*id*, personA_id → Persons, personB_id → Persons}

The code that I have written is:

```
SELECT distinct P1.name, COUNT(P2.id)
FROM Persons P1
INNER JOIN Likes L
    On P1.id = L.PersonA_id
INNER JOIN Persons P2
    ON P2.id = L.PersonB_id
WHERE P2.eyeColor = "green" 
AND COUNT(P2.id) >= 2
GROUP BY name
```

What do I have to do to make it work?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please clarify what problem you're having with this query. Does it give you errors when you try to run it for example, or does it give you wrong results?

Comment: it gives me an Invalid use of group function. I am not sure if I am using the right structure and queries to acquire the answer.

Comment: Can you attach the entire error into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT and GROUP BY clauses should use the same colum - P1.name. "*COUNT(P2.id) >= 2*" should be used in HAVING clause not in WHERE

```
SELECT
  P1.name,
  COUNT(P2.id)
FROM
  Persons P1
  INNER JOIN Likes L On P1.id = L.PersonA_id
  INNER JOIN Persons P2 ON P2.id = L.PersonB_id
WHERE
  P2.eyeColor = "green" 
GROUP BY
  P1.name
HAVING
  COUNT(P2.id) >= 2
```